# Substituir esse simbolo do Wordpress (Lista de itens)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Ao colocar um conteúdo de um arquivo do pdf para o Wordpress, as listas de itens aparecem como esse simbolo estranho, em vez das tradicionais bolinhas.

Há uma maneira de eu substituir dinamicamente sem ter que apagar uma por uma? (O que geraria um trabalho manual muito grande, já que são muitos arquivos)

[image: Simbolo estranho]

Comment: Isso provavelmente será da propriedade `list-style-type` do CSS, mas sem ver é difícil dizer ao certo.

Comment: Verifica se a fonte e a codificação do pdf é a mesma do WordPress. Isso tá parecendo caractere não mapeado.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas como eu verificaria isso?